# Summarizing a Data Frame for graphing in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have the following data frame.  It  details the yearly cost of 4 different spending scenarios each with three years.

```
mydf2 = data.frame( Scenario = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), Year= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), 
Cost = c(140,445,847,948,847,143,554,30,44,554,89,45))
```

I want to be able to graph the total yearly cost of all scenarios  I have:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf2, aes(x = Year, y= Cost))+ geom_line(stat="identity")
```

but it produces this terrible looking graph:

[image]

When I summarize the data by year it works but I don't know how to do this in R.  I have to go back to Excel.  How do I summarize the data frame by year so it can be graphed? The new frame will look like this:

```
 Year   Total Cost
  1      2196
  2      1411
  3      1079
```

But again I have to go back to Excel to do it. I don't know why those vertical lines persist either.  I am new to R so thanks very much.

Comment: Do you want one plot per scenario or one plot overall that summarize everything?

Comment: Yes I would also like that.  the immediate need was one plot to summarize everything, but I also will need to plot each scenario individually.  If you can offer that would like it very much too.  thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ggplot way to do this is:

```
ggplot(mydf2, aes(x = Year, y= Cost)) + stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "line")
```

Another option is to use dplyr to summarise the data and "pipe" it right into ggplot.

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
mydf2 %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(Cost = sum(Cost)) %>% 
   ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Cost)) + geom_line(stat = "identity")
```

The `.` inside ggplot is the data that is passed through the pipe with `%>%`.

If you wanted to make one plot per scenario, you can use `facet_wrap` for example. I don't use `stat_summary` here since each scenario has only 1 entry per year i.e. no aggregation necessary:

```
ggplot(mydf2, aes(x = Year, y= Cost)) + 
   geom_line(stat = "identity") + 
   facet_wrap( ~ Scenario)
```

If you want to plot each scenario with a separate line but in the same plot, you can do:

```
ggplot(mydf2, aes(x = Year, y= Cost, color = factor(Scenario))) + 
    geom_line(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: The first option worked well, but with the second I get an error stating "Error in ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Cost)) : object '.' not found"

Comment: You need to install and load the package dplyr in order to use that second option. It should work then.

Comment: @docendodiscimus regarding his comment on his question maybe you could edit your answer like that:
```mydf2 %>% group_by(Scenario,Year) %>% summarise(Cost = sum(Cost)) %>% 
     ggplot(., aes(x = Year, y = Cost)) + geom_line(stat = "identity")+facet_wrap(~Scenario)```

Comment: I already included an option with facetting in my answer - at the bottom

Comment: Thanks facet_wrap worked well.  Gave a tiled result.  How would I get it one the same plot?